# How to split two ir sensor data to different file?

Tags: python, arduino

First, I am using Arduino code receive the sensor data, then make the python output sensor data to text file for save, the problem is two sensor data write to the same file, how can I split it to two different files to save?

arduino code:

```
int counter = 0;
int counter2 = 0;

int laststate = HIGH;
int laststate2 = HIGH;

const int irReceiver = 2;              
const int irReceiver2 = 6;

const int irLed  = 3;                    
const int irLed2  = 4;                    

const int ledPin = 13;                  
const int ledPin2 = 14;                


const unsigned int frequency = 38000;   
const unsigned int frequency2 = 38000; 


void setup() {                
  Serial.begin(9600);     
  pinMode(irReceiver, INPUT);    
  pinMode(irReceiver2, INPUT);

  pinMode(irLed, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(irLed2, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT); 

  tone(irLed, frequency); 
  tone(irLed2, frequency2); 
}

void blinkLED() {
  for (int i=1; i<= 4; i++) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(100);
  }  
}

void blinkLED2() {
  for (int i=1; i<= 4; i++) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW); 
    delay(100);
  }  
}


void loop() {
  int ir_status = digitalRead(irReceiver); 
  int ir_status2 = digitalRead(irReceiver2);

  if (laststate == LOW && ir_status == HIGH) // only count on a LOW-> HIGH transition
  {
     counter++;
     Serial.println(" A zone:");
     Serial.println(counter);
  }
  laststate = ir_status; 

 if (laststate2 == LOW && ir_status2 == HIGH) // only count on a LOW-> HIGH transition
  {
     counter2++;
     Serial.println("B zone:");
     Serial.println(counter2);
  }
  laststate2 = ir_status2;  // remember last state

  if (ir_status == 0)                      
    blinkLED();                             
  if (ir_status2 == 0)                      
    blinkLED2();                           
}
```

This python part read all output in Arduino code, I want to only read first sensor, how to do?
python code:

```
 import serial
    connected = False
    locations=['/dev/ttyUSB0']

for device in locations:

    try:
        print "Trying...", device

        ser = serial.Serial(device, 9600)

        break

    except:

        print "Failed to connect on",device

while not connected:

    serin = ser.read()

    connected = True

text_file = open("position4.txt", 'w')

while 1:

    if ser.inWaiting():

        x=ser.read()

        print(x) 

        text_file.write(x)

        if x=="":

             text_file.seek(0)

             text_file.truncate()

        text_file.flush()
enter code here

text_file.close()

ser.close()
```

Comment: IndentationError: unexpected indent

Answer (score 0):

You've probably missed a very important part of those examples - the lines that follow the "recv()" call

```
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```